# django view synchronization

Tags: python, django, graph, synchronization, view

I need to create a page where one part of the page is the result of a fairly long calculation and the other part is a graph that shows some interim results of the calculation. The way I implemented it is that I have two views. One view does the calculation and stores the interim results in a session variable. The second view retrieves the interim results from the session variable and displays the values with matplotlib as an image.

The issue is that I cannot find a way to have the second view execute after the first view is done. If the second view executes first then I see the old data in the graph.

Here is some pseudo code:

views.py:

```
def calc(request):
  ...
  do calculations
  store interim results in session variable
  return render_to_response(...'result':value...)

def graph(request)
  retrieve interim results from session variable
  create and return HttpResponse(content_type='image/png') with graph
```

urls.py:

```
(r'^report/$', 'calc',),
(r'^report/graph.png/$', 'graph',),
```

resultAndGraph.html:

```
Result: {{result}}
<img src="graph.png" width="400" height="400">
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a session variable, I would suggest you setup [Memcache](http://memcached.org/) and use the [Django Caching framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs)

If you want to use two views though, you could redirect from the first view to the second one, using an [HttpResponseRedirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect)

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestion. I will consider it. Do you have any comment about the synchronization of the call to calc() and graph()? If I understand it correctly then the different sort of caching will not help me with the synchronization issue.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by synchronization. If you want to have one view execute about the first one you could use a redirect, but it will still be slow to load

Answer (score 0):

If you have a long-running process, use a task queue like [celery](http://celeryproject.org/) and offload the task to a separate process.

In your second view simply check if this process is done, and then display the updated information (it can also display a notice that the process is still running).

Integrating with django is easy via [`django-celery`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery) which uses the caching mechanism suggested by @cberner.